# How to get all the Spark config along with default config?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working on a project for which I need to collect all the Spark config. 
The problem is that if a parameter is not explicitly set, I would need the default value. Is there a way to get all the config, including all defaults?

I tried with:

- `sc.getConf.getAll`, but in this way, I do not get the defaults.
- `SparkListener`, in order to get some specific information (for example the number of executors), but I couldn't find a way to get other needed information like the number of cores per executor, memory per executor etc...